# As population increases the SIR model graph should shift left. And the recovery & transmission rate trackbars don't work at all

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to simulate the spread of a virus using the SIR model in VB.net but my code doesn't work.

increase initial infections: should shift graph left (but mine doesn't)
increase Population:  shifts graph left (but mine doesn't)
increase Susceptible:  shifts graph left (but mine doesn't)
increase transmission rate (b): increases peak of 'infectives' curve (but my trackbar doesn't work at all - produces an overflow error)
increase recovery rate (a):  'infectives' peak decreases, while the other two lines go up

This is what the graph *should* do: https://faradars.org/ev/sir-simulator/?lang=en

These images demonstrate the errors in my code that I don't know how to fix:

[image: One]

[image: Two]

[image: Three]

[image: Four]

Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    'initail values  
    Dim N As Double = 10000
    Dim S As Double = 8000
    Dim R = 0.0
    Dim I As Double = N - S - R


    Dim t As Double = 0
    Dim b As Double = 2 'contact rate
    Dim a As Double = 0.5 'removal rate
    Dim scale As Double = 0.1



    setupForm(N, S, I, R, t, b, a, scale)
    ProccessGraph()
End Sub

Sub setupForm(N, S, I, R, t, b, a, scale)

    'Trackbars
    Dim tbData(7) As Decimal
    tbData(1) = N           'population N
    tbData(2) = S           'Susceptibles S
    tbData(3) = I           'infectives I
    tbData(4) = R           'Recoveries R
    tbData(5) = t           'time t
    tbData(6) = b           'infection rate b
    tbData(7) = a           'removal rate a
    Dim y As Integer = 10
    For I = 1 To 7
        Dim Tbar As New TrackBar
        With Tbar
            .Location = New Point(20, y)
            .Size = New Size(140, 30)
            .BackColor = Color.White
            .Minimum = 0
            .Maximum = 10000
            .SmallChange = 1
            .Name = "Trackbar" & I
            .Value = tbData(I)
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(Tbar)



        'labels (display value) ✓
        Dim labvalue As New Label
        With labvalue
            .Location = New Point(180, y)
            .Name = "label" & I
            .Size = New Size(50, 15)
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(labvalue)


        'labels (tbar title) ✓
        Dim labtitle_data(7) As String
        labtitle_data(1) = "Population N"
        labtitle_data(2) = "Susceptibles S"
        labtitle_data(3) = "Infectives I"
        labtitle_data(4) = "Recoveries R"
        labtitle_data(5) = "time"
        labtitle_data(6) = "infection rate"
        labtitle_data(7) = "removal rate"
        Dim labtitle As New Label
        With labtitle
            .Location = New Point(240, y)
            .Name = "label" & I
            .Size = New Size(60, 60)
            .Text = labtitle_data(I)
        End With
        y += 60
        Me.Controls.Add(labtitle)


        'ComboBox (to list countries) ✓
        Dim cb1 As New ComboBox
        cb1.Items.Add("China")
        cb1.Location = New Point(990, 50)
        Me.Controls.Add(cb1)


        'Form properties ✓
        Me.Size = New Size(1200, 500)
        Me.BackColor = Color.White

        AddHandler Tbar.ValueChanged, AddressOf ProccessGraph 'every time the value changes, recreate the graph to match it
    Next
End Sub

Sub ProccessGraph()
    Dim tblist(7) As TrackBar 'array of trackbars
    For tbar = 1 To 7
        tblist(tbar) = Me.Controls("TrackBar" & tbar)
        Me.Controls("label" & tbar).Text = tblist(tbar).Value 'adds value to label
    Next
    'reset NSIR values to match trackbar values
    Dim N = tblist(1).Value
    Dim S = tblist(2).Value
    Dim I = tblist(3).Value
    Dim R = tblist(4).Value
    Dim t = tblist(5).Value


    Dim b = tblist(6).Value
    'Dim a = tblist(7).Value
    Dim a As Double = 0.5
    Dim scale As Double = 0.1
    'b = tblist(6).Value
    'a = tblist(7).Value



    'chart lines ✓
    Chart1.Series.Clear()
    Chart1.Titles.Clear()
    Dim serS As New Series
    Dim serI As New Series
    Dim serR As New Series
    serS.Name = "S"
    serS.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    serS.BorderWidth = 2
    serI.Name = "I"
    serI.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    serI.BorderWidth = 2
    serR.Name = "R"
    serR.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    serR.BorderWidth = 2

    'chart calculations ✓
    For ind = 0 To 99
        serS.Points.AddXY(t, S)
        serI.Points.AddXY(t, I)
        serR.Points.AddXY(t, R)
        Dim ds = (-b * S * I) / N
        Dim Di = ((b * S * I) / N) - a * I
        Dim Dr = a * I
        Dim dt = 1
        S = S + ds * scale
        I = I + Di * scale
        R = R + Dr * scale
        t = t + dt * scale
    Next
    'chart properties ✓
    Chart1.Series.Add(serS)
    Chart1.Series.Add(serI)
    Chart1.Series.Add(serR)
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Title = "Days"
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Title = "Population"
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Interval = 10
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Interval = 500
    Chart1.Titles.Add("SIR Graph")
    Chart1.Location = New Point(280, 30)
    Chart1.Size = New Size(700, 400)

    ''trackbar colors which, remember, are only accessible via the array tbs
    'tblist(1).BackColor = Color.LightGray
    'tblist(2).BackColor = Color.Blue
    'tblist(3).BackColor = Color.Yellow
    'tblist(4).BackColor = Color.LightCoral
  End Sub
End Class`
```

Existing SIR models:
https://faradars.org/ev/sir-simulator/?lang=en

Existing SIR models code:
https://www.google.com/amp/s/jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2020/02/11/the-kermack-mckendrick-sir-disease-model-using-c/amp/
https://github.com/henrifroese/infectious_disease_modelling/blob/master/part_two.ipynb

Comment: provide more details what is the problem where you need help with? code doesn't work means it does not compile or logic issues..etc.

Comment: ok thank you. The code does run, it just doesn't do what it's supposed to do. Increase in trackbar "N", "S" and "I" should shift the graph left, as shown by this similar simulation: https://faradars.org/ev/sir-simulator/?lang=en. Also as initial 'S' is increased on the trackbar, 'I' should decrease appropriately but as I increase one trackbar, the other remains the same. When I try to change the transmission rate on the trackbar, an overflow error is produced. Code is based of this: https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2020/02/11/the-kermack-mckendrick-sir-disease-model-using-c/

Comment: This appears to be vb.net code. Please remove the C# tag.